# HandlerExceptionResolver not invoking in clustered environment

Tags: java, spring, servlets

I have written one class that implements `HandlerExceptionResolver` of spring to handle the `MaxUploadSizeExceededException` expception because we allow at max 25MB size for upload. I have registered this class in the servletcontext as follows:

```
<bean id="uploadingFileSizeExceeds" 
  class="com.puresafety.health.ui.web.demographics.controllers.FileSizeExceedsMaxLimitHandler" >
</bean>
```

Class **FileSizeExceedsMaxLimitHandler**

```
public class FileSizeExceedsMaxLimitHandler implements HandlerExceptionResolver {
    private final static Log logger = LogFactory
            .getLog(FileSizeExceedsMaxLimitHandler.class);

    public ModelAndView resolveException(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) {
        logger.debug("FileSizeExceedsMaxLimitHandler.resolveException: Control is coming here because uploading file size is exceeding max allowed limit.");
        if (ex instanceof MaxUploadSizeExceededException
                && request.getPathInfo().equals(
                        "/demographicsPhoto/uploadimagefile")) {
            logger.debug("FileSizeExceedsMaxLimitHandler.resolveException: MaxUploadSizeExceededException occurred");
            request.setAttribute("ALERTMESSAGE",
                    "The image size is exceeding the allowed limit.");
            ImageUploadForm imageUploadForm = new ImageUploadForm();
            Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            model.put("imageUploadForm", imageUploadForm);
            return new ModelAndView("demographics/uploadEmployeeImage", model);
        }
        return new ModelAndView("base/error/error404");
    }
}
```

It's catching the exception successfully in my local but not working in our Clustered QA environment i.e. control is not going to the method resolveException in this class.

What I am missing here.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: show us your FileSizeExceedsMaxLimitHandler class.

Comment: public class FileSizeExceedsMaxLimitHandler implements HandlerExceptionResolver
{
 private final static Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(FileSizeExceedsMaxLimitHandler.class);

 public ModelAndView resolveException(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
           Object handler, Exception ex)
 {
  logger.debug("FileSizeExceedsMaxLimitHandler.resolveException: Control is coming here because uploading file size is exceeding max allowed limit.");
  if(ex instanceof MaxUploadSizeExceededException && request.getPathInfo().equals("/demographicsPhoto/uploadimagefile"))
  {

Comment: logger.debug("FileSizeExceedsMaxLimitHandler.resolveException: MaxUploadSizeExceededException occurred");
   request.setAttribute("ALERTMESSAGE", "The image size is exceeding the allowed limit.");
   ImageUploadForm imageUploadForm = new ImageUploadForm();
   Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
   model.put("imageUploadForm", imageUploadForm);
   return new ModelAndView("demographics/uploadEmployeeImage", model);
  }
  return new ModelAndView("base/error/error404");
 }
}

Comment: @SajanChandran                                                       Sorry for late reply..I am new to stackoverflow and didn't get the way to put entire class in one shot due to comment length restriction & don't know alternative to provide the entire file in one shot, so I provided my entire file in two comments.

Comment: you can edit your question and you can add your code to the original question itself.

Comment: I have a suspicion that your request could be failing even before that(Before it gets to maxuploadsize problem). Are you able to upload smaller sized files? Maybe the path you are trying to upload to does not exist or the user running the server does not have permissions to that path in your clustered environment. Check the logs to make sure.